# Providing Guest VM to connect to Internet through Host on ESXi with only one adapter

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I am new to virtualized environment. I have a bare-metal server provided by a hosting company which has ESXi 6.5 running on it. It has only one physical adapter, one Management Network and one VM Network, which has the virtual machine. I want to allow VM to access internet through the host connection. Will it be possible? I am planning to create a private LAN and make the current VM as a domain controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You can see a vSwitch0 in Virtual Switches Tab in web console of ESXi, that VM Network and Management Network both are connected to it and also the physical NIC is also connected to it.

If your configuration of your physical NIC be correct, you just need to create a virtual machine with a network adapter that is connected to VM Network port group.

To check the configuration of your physical NIC, at the ESXi console, press F2 and check 'Configure Management Network'.